# Cannot Install CocoaPods

Tags: terminal, installation, cocoapods

I am having trouble installing CocoaPods. When i try `sudo gem install cocoapods`,
it gives me an error saying `ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it work by manually installing a compatible activesupport first.

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 1):

you need upgrade your ruby version or install old version of cocoapod.Current ruby version on your system not enough for dependencies.

installing old version of cocoapods

```bash
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.25.0 // pick minimum viable version for your system
```

if you want keep with latest version of cocoapods [this](https://shellzero.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-update-ruby-2-0-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os-x-yosemite/) article will help you upgrade your ruby on your system.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```